# VBA in MS Access live search doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently working on a database with MS Access 365.
I am using the filtering of access to create a live-search in my form.
Everything works fine until I want to add a blank space in my Search or If I type something in, that is not contained in the database.

The Code I am using looks like the following:

```
Private Sub SearchBox_Change()
' https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/05/03/using-a-combo-box-to-search-as-you-type/
If Nz(Me.SearchBox.Text) = "" Then
    Me.Form.Filter = ""
    Me.Form.FilterOn = False
'If a partial value is typed, filter for a partial company name match.
Else
    Me.Form.Filter = "Nachname Like '*" & Me.SearchBox.Text & "*'"
    Me.Form.FilterOn = True
End If

'Move the cursor to the end of the combo box.
Me.SearchBox.SetFocus
Me.SearchBox.SelStart = Len(Me.SearchBox.Text)
End Sub
```

The main problem is, that it causes a runtime error 2185 if I type in something which can not be filtered instead of just giving an empty result. '*You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus*'.
If I try debugging it says, It is caused by the last line.

The second problem is, that if I want to add a blank space in my searchbox it doesn't work, because the `len`-function rightfully ignores the blanks. Do you have any idea on how to avoid this errors. Please ask If you need further information.

Comment: (1) I would create a subroutine-level variable that gets assigned the `.Text` value once at the top. Replace further instances of `.Text` with the variable name to avoid error 2185   
(2) The `Len` function definitely *does* count blanks

Comment: Sadly that did not help. The Len function does count blanks except for leading blanks which are necessary to be able to type in blanks.

Comment: Regarding the Error 2185, do you have a `SearchBox_GotFocus()` event that is changing the focus to some other control?

Comment: If you doubt me, try it yourself: `Len("    ab    ")` always returns 4. Blanks count. The culprit is likely Access -- make a string variable strText and put the line strText = SearchBox.Text at the beginning of the event handler. When you inspect the value of strText, are the blanks removed?

Comment: I do not doubt you, if I output your suggestion it does count the blanks, it just does not work, when I type into the field. It now works with `If Not (Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0) Then
    Me.SearchBox.SelStart = SearchLen
End If`

Comment: Is `SearchBox` bound to a field in an underlying query? Typically such a control would be unbound. If `SearchBox` is bound, it would explain why the spaces went away, because Access trims spaces before saving the value to the table. Anyway, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Yes, it is bound to a query. I did a few more changes now and everything works great. thank you!